# Attachments get duplicated in mails received which are sent using SendGridMessage LoadSendGridTemplate<T>()

Tags: c#-2.0, sendgrid-api-v3

We are using SendGridMessage's LoadSendGridTemplate(string templateId, EmailMessage emailMessage, T model, params string[] attachments) method to bind model data and attachments to sendgrid template for email sending functionality. After execution of these method, attachments gets double count.
For example, if I am sending 3 files path as an string array of attachments, after execution of the above "SendGridMessage LoadSendGridTemplate(string templateId, EmailMessage emailMessage, T model, params string[] attachments)" method, the count of attachments became 6.[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMapw.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xZv8.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWAzB.jpg)
what is the reason?

Attachments should not get duplicated